# Change hyperlink text to dropdown on click and back

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, combobox, kendo-ui

So I have a label/text that can be a hyperlink, that I need to change to a Kendo Combobox (in a div). Is there a way, in javascript, that I can show and hide or alter between a label and the combobox on click of the text.

So my desired output is:

1. click on text, combobox displays, click away from label, combobox disappears and text is back with selected value from combobox

Currently my code looks like the following:

```
<div id="siteText" onclick="showcombo()"> <a href="#">Site</a>  </div>
<div id="combobox" hidden>
    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
                .Name("DDLSiteID")
                .DataTextField("SiteName")
                .DataValueField("SiteID")
                .BindTo((List<SitesClass>)ViewData["Sites"])
                .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                .Value(Model.SiteID.ToString())
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 300px;" })
                .Events(e => e.Change("onSiteChange"))
            )
</div>

<script>

function showcombo(e) { ///what do I do here? }

function onSiteChange(e) {
    $("#SiteID").val(e.sender.element[0].value);

    console.log("Site selected: ", $("#SiteID").val());

}
```

So what I need is to be able to click the site hyperlink value and it changes to the combobox, then when I select a value from the combobox, it changes the hyperlink value to the selected text and the combobox changes back to showing just the hyperlink.

I've seen this done before, but can't remember where. I'm not sure if it is as simple as hiding the one div and showing the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  
    <style type="text/css">
      #combobox-container {
        display: none
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="siteText"><a href="#">Site</a></div>
<div id="combobox-container">
  <input id="combobox" />
</div>
<script>
$("#combobox").kendoComboBox({
  dataSource: {
    data: [{
      text: 'Test 1',
      value: 1
    },{
      text: 'Test 2',
      value: 2
    },{
      text: 'Test 3',
      value: 3
    }]
  },
  dataTextField: 'text',
  dataValueField: 'value',
  change: function() {
    console.log(this.value());
  }
});
  
  $("#siteText").on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#combobox-container").show();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  
  $('#combobox-container').on('click', '*', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  
  $('body').on('click', function() {
    $('#siteText').show();
    $("#combobox-container").hide();
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/UHUTEFoG)